# Getting Property does not override any property from its superclass in Swift with UICollectionCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

```
extension UICollectionViewCell
{
  override var isSelected: Bool
   {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = isSelected ? UIColor.black : UIColor.blue
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to override the var isSelected inside UICollectionView Cell but I am getting an error saying that "Getting Property does not override any property from its superclass".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making an extension to `UICollectionViewCell` does exactly that, **extends** the `UICollectionViewCell` class functionality without subclassing it. `isSelected` property has already been declared in the same class.

If you want to override `isSelected` property you have to subclass `UICollectionViewCell`, like:

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = isSelected ? .black : .blue
        }
    }
}
```

You can find more for [extensions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html) in the official documentation.